# Countdown Today date in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The code below is working perfectly, but when I change the date to today's date (for example: 2016/01/06 05:00:00) then the countdown will show to 00 days 00:00:00, but still got 4 hour need to count down. How can I do it?

```
<span class='countdown' value='2016/01/06 05:00:00'></span><br />
<span class='countdown' value='2016/04/06 23:59:59'></span><br />
<span class='countdown' value='2016/05/07 01:15:15'></span><br />

$(function(){
    $('.countdown').each(function(){
        $(this).countdown($(this).attr('value'), function(event) {
        $(this).text(
        event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
      );
        });
    });
});
```

> a jsFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/smh5nhgz/1/

Comment: it's taking month  as month-1 from given month https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/smh5nhgz/5/

Comment: Hmm it's working for me in your jsfiddle. Are you sure you're inputing your time correctly?

Comment: 2016/01/06 05:00:00 result for this one is 00 days 00:00:00 because 05:00:00 is treated as 05AM. If you change it to 18:00:00 or more than the current hour of the current time, it will countdown.

Answer (score 1):

The countdown worked fine for me.

```
<span class='countdown' value='2016/01/06 05:00:00'></span><br />
```

It shows 00 days **00:00:00** only if the set time is greater than the current time. I was able to get a 4 hour count down.

Comment: Try changing your system time and verify. I did the same to get the 4hr Countdown. That way you might be able to know the exact scenario.

Even if I share a working fiddle, our time zones may vary.Better follow the above approach